# jsonb find to array

Tags: json, postgresql

структура json

```
[{"to": 5, "from": 1, "country": 1}, {"to": 11, "from": 6, "country": 2}, {"to": 20, "from": 12, "country": 3}]

SELECT column_json::jsonb FROM table WHERE column_json::jsonb ....;
```

подскажите, что написать в WHERE если мне надо вытащить `country='1'` и `'3'` `BETWEEN column_json.from AND column_json.to`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT test.id, parsed.element
FROM test
CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(data) AS parsed (element)
WHERE jsonb_extract_path(parsed.element, 'country')::INT = 1
AND 3 BETWEEN jsonb_extract_path(parsed.element, 'from')::INT 
          AND jsonb_extract_path(parsed.element, 'to')::INT
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5c374bb942641b5db68a32267e3739a3

Если поле имеет тип, отличный от JSONB - используйте JSON-версии функций или явно приводите тип.

Comment: Возможно ли построить этот запрос без использования
CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(data) AS parsed (element) ?

Comment: @1game Нет. Ну то есть можно вместо CROSS JOIN поставить запятую - а смысл? И главное - а почему, откуда такое странное пожелание?

Comment: при использовании CROSS JOIN массив [{"to": 5, "from": 1, "country": 1}, {"to": 11, "from": 6, "country": 2}, {"to": 20, "from": 12, "country": 3}] делится на 3 строки - сразу не понял как сделать так что бы удовлетворяло мои требования, необходимо было для фильтрации данных, сейчас все как надо, спасибо за помощь